# How to create an alertview with search bar in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uialertview, searchbar

I want to display an alert view with a search bar option on it. How can I create a search bar in a alert view? Any sample codes would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a search bar and and added the text box as its subview.

```
UIAlertView * myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"         " 
                                                       message:@"         "
                                                      delegate:self 
                                             cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
UISearchBar *myTextField = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0, 35.0, 180.0, 35.0)];
UIButton *searchbtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230.0, 35.0, 40.0, 35.0)];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[myAlertView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[searchbtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
[myAlertView addSubview:searchbtn];
```

If there is any other better way please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way:

```
    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Keyword Search" 
                                                           message:@""
                                                          delegate:self 
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                 otherButtonTitles:@"Search", nil] autorelease];

    myAlertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [myAlertView show];
```

And in the Delegate:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *searchTerm = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
}
```